Server Error in '/' Application. Parser Error Description
I am having this issue while launching my project, I can't start my project as I get this error:

An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'xxxxxxxxx.LU.xxxxx.Client.Website.Global'. Source Error: Line 1: <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="xxxxxxxx.LU.xxx.Client.Website.Global" Language="C#"

With a status server error 500.
Can you help me out?
I have tried to Clean and Rebuild solution.
I am expecting my project to be able to launch without any issue.

Check your Global.asax file be located in the root of the web application directory. When you add this file to the project, it should reside in the same directory as your web application's main files (like Web.config, Default.aspx, etc.).
Then ensure that the namespace in your Global.asax matches the namespace in your Global.asax.cs .
If there are no issues with the previous step, try the following:
Delete the Global.asax and Global.asax.cs files. Add a new item by selecting 'Global Application Class' and name it Global.asax. Check namespaces in two files. Try Re-build.
